# How to open a browser to show the content of a file?

Tags: javascript, enyo

I trying to open a txt document in a enyo application for mobile and I didn't found anything, so can I open that file on the mobile browser or inside the application using javascript or other way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Ajax to request the file and the place the response into the content of an instance of a `Control`.  i.e.:

```
{name: "textfile"}
```

...

```
this.$.textfile.setContent(inResponse.data);
```

If you wanted to have HTML in it then you'll need to set the `allowHtml` property to `true`.

Check out https://github.com/enyojs/enyo/wiki/Consuming-Web-Services for more info on Ajax. And, yes, you use Ajax to request local (on device) files, too.

Comment: Thank you! We use the Ajax option and worked with text and similar files. But there is a way to open files like .pdf, images and zip's?

Comment: Check these:  https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ and http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/